# How to use facet query along with facet field in solarium?

Tags: solr, facet, solarium

I want alist of cities in facet for a particular list of states in fq.

So my query is:

```
fq: {!tag=state}state_id:(25 41)

facet query: state_id:(25 41)

facet field: {!ex=state}city_id
```

This works perfectly fine in Solr Admin, whereas when I query it using Solarium:

```
    $facetSet->createFacetQuery('city')->setQuery($facet_q);
    $facetSet->createFacetField(array('field'=>'city','exclude'=>'state'));
```

it gives an empty result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might use customizer request plugin of soalrium. http://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugins/#customizerequest-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but the same question is relevant also today.

You can do the following with solarium v6:

```
$query->createFilterQuery('FilterName')->setQuery('price:340')->addTag('price');
```

This will be translated to:

```
fq={!tag=price}price:340
```

Also:

```
$facetSet = $query->getFacetSet();
$facetSet->createFacetField('FacetName')->setField('price')->getLocalParameters()->addExcludes(['price']);
```

This will be translated to:

```
facet.field={!key=FacetName ex=price}price&facet=true
```

So as you can see addTag and addExclude should be used.